# How to turn a while loop into a do while loop?

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch, max = 0;
  int n = 0;
  cout << "Enter number of characters! :";
  cin >> n;
  cout << "Enter the number";
  while (n>0)
  {
      cin >> ch;
      if(max<ch)
          max = ch;
      n=n-1;

  }
  cout << "max is : " << max;
}
```

I'm trying to turn it into a do while loop - here's what I have:

```
int main()
{
char ch, max = 0;
int n = 0;
cout << "enter character";
cin >> n;
cout << "enter two";
cin >> ch;
do
      (max<ch);

while
(max = ch);
(n>0);
n= n - 1;

      cout << "max is : " << max;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is that your actual code or was there an error at posting.

Comment: Why would you want to turn this into a `do { ... } while (condition)` loop? What if the user enters zero for the "number of characters"?

Comment: the first code works fine..the 2nd code when I run..I type 3 then 123 and nothing happens

Comment: @johnmath15 Do you know how do while loops work?

Comment: `while (max = ch);` will cause an infinite loop if `ch` is non-zero.

Comment: Since there is no *question* in this post, I vote to close. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before your next post.

Comment: Just change `while(...){...}` to `do{...}while(...);`. Note the semicolon, and watch out for cases where the initial conditions don't pass the test.

Answer (score 4):

The first program needs to check for EOF or other failures after the extractor is used:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch, max = 0;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of characters: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the number: ";
    while (n > 0 && cin)
    {
        if (cin >> ch && max < ch)
            max = ch;
        n = n - 1;
    }
    cout << "max is : " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I note that there is nothing in the code that enforces 'it is a number' beyond the hint in the prompt.  Further, most interfaces that make the user count something that the computer could count instead are misguided.

There is very little point in converting the code to use a `do ... while` loop, but if you must, then it ends up looking like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch, max = 0;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of characters: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the number: ";
    if (n > 0 && cin)
    {
        do
        {
            if (cin >> ch && max < ch)
                max = ch;
            n = n - 1;
        } while (n > 0 && cin);
    }

    cout << "max is : " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note the condition that appeared at the top of the `while` loop is now a separate `if` condition and is repeated in the `do ... while (...)` condition.  This alone tells you that `do ... while` is inappropriate here; you only want to go through the loop if there is work to do, but a `do ... while` loop forces you through the loop once regardless.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (test) block;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (test) {
  do block
  while (test);
}
```

so your while loop would be changed into

```
if (n>0) {
  do {
    cin >> ch;
    if(max<ch)
      max = ch;
    n=n-1;
  } while (n>0);
}
```